# Disk cloned with CloneZilla does not boot ( end up in grub prompt)

Tags: linux, boot, grub, clone

I did a complete clone of a disk (disk-to-disk with all partitions) using Clonezilla.

The exact option I took was: device-device work directly from a disk or partition to a disk or partition

I had both disks attached to the same server, I booted from CloneZilla (beginner mode) on a USB stick, I selected the source disk (not partition, the whole disk) and the destination disk (also the whole disk). Both disks are identical in size ( 36 GB).

I saw it cloning the MBR and all other partitions (including the larger root one). It did a lot of other post operations, but it was too fast to understand everything.

The clone was successful but when I try to boot, it fails and I end up with the GRUB prompt.

The disk contains a Centos 7 installation and I understand that grub refers to the boot partition via its UUID (in grub.cfg) and the same UUID is used in /etc/fstab for the /boot partition. However, if I clone the disk, don't I also clone the UUIDs, and then grub and fstab should find the right partition.

In fact, here is the output from blkid for the 2 disks (source and cloned one). We can see that their partitions have the same UUID:

```
# blkid
/dev/mapper/cl-root: UUID="f382f255-65f1-417a-b7f7-2b5c2fd544f5" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="F0QMzP-AeG3-jc0f-Gqzc-AO18-9x4w-crqBHf" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sda1: UUID="87527c10-98fc-4a99-a62b-6f4e18a0a7a1" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="87527c10-98fc-4a99-a62b-6f4e18a0a7a1" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="F0QMzP-AeG3-jc0f-Gqzc-AO18-9x4w-crqBHf" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/cl-swap: UUID="8b5cc83e-a342-4d83-8872-693efa1632b2" TYPE="swap"
```

What is wrong with this hypothesis? Do the actual partition id change during the cloning process? What is the difference between the original disk and the cloned disk that makes the original disk boot normally and the cloned one fails to boot?

I guess I would like to understand why the cloned disk does not boot but also how to fix it.

Thank you!

Gilbert

Comment: Perhaps it didn't actually do the full disk clone, but mbr + all partitions clone. (So the gaps are omitted, one of which is where the grub core.img resides)

Comment: I just found about the -j1 option in CloneZilla: "-j1 (default: unchecked): "Write MBR (512 B) again after image is restored. Not OK for partition table differ from that of the image" In some cases, sfdisk uses different CHS values to create the partition table (due to different kernels have different CHS values of hard drive), and it will make the restore OS fail to boot. ( https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/88_mbr_related_options.faq#88_mbr_related_options.faq ) . I will try that.